# Show module only on the start page

Tags: module, smartsearch, module-params

I've made a finder plugin which creates router links to my component. If there is no menu link available (especially when the found item is in a subcategory) the route of the item in the finder plugin has the ItemId of the start (home) page. The problem is that I've enabled a module on the start page. If somebody does now a search on that site and clicks on the found item the module will be shown, but I want to hide it. An example can be found here

https://joomla.digital-peak.com/component/finder/search?q=google&Itemid=1098

Is there a way to define in the module parameters that it should be shown only when it is on the Home_Root and no path is specified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a module is assigned on a specific item id, then it will be displayed, when this itemid exists in the url.

1. You could create a specific menu item, probably hidden, for the display of the links, where you can assign only the modules you want to display.
2. In such cases, it comes handy the [**Advanced Module Manager**](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager) by NoNumbers, which gives you much more control on where & when a module will be displayed. There is a free version to try it.

Comment: I concur with using Advanced Module Manager. Short of adding some logic into your module, it's the easiest way to force something ONLY load on the front page and nowhere else.

Comment: I think option #1 is a quicker and cleaner solution to this problem. Installing a 2 MB+ component only to manage 1 module position sounds like overkill. Although admittedly Advanced Module Manager is a great and useful extension with many uses.